# Bash: How can I check if a website has finished loading?

Tags: bash, command-line, firefox, xdotool

**Problem**

I am trying to automate a task in my Firefox browser with `xdotool`.

First, I open a new tab in my browser with:

```
firefox -new-tab "www.domain.tld"
```

Then (after the page [www.domain.tld](http://www.domain.tld) has finished loading) I want to perform a task:

```
if [ <page has fully loaded> ]
then
    <commands>
fi
```

How can I detect whether the page has finished loading in bash?

**Workaround**

At the moment I use `sleep 5` (wait 5 seconds until calling the next command) which is a a bit hacky because some pages load really fast and others don't.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to use something designed for browser automation?

Comment: Normally yes. In my case no. I want to save several (hundred) web pages as pdf and the only tool that gives me the desired result was Firefox. The problem is that there are svg images which are rendered on each page load on every page and all other tools I tried break them.

Comment: But why do you need a GUI then? This feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I suggest you explain what you are trying to do and ask for solutions to that instead of trying to force bash to do something it is really not designed to do.

Comment: I have tried all tools (like `wkhtmltopdf`) to save a scientific website with formulas provided by [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/) and grafics provided by [JSXGraph](https://jsxgraph.org/wp/index.html) as a pdf file. Only Firefox saves the website correctly and I'm sorry [there is no CLI argument for printing yet](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1407238). Not even Chrome works (in my case) because of some known bugs/missing features. I would be happy if this was a XY problem.

Comment: Please post your workaround as an answer. That's a really clever trick, changing the window title via javascript!

Comment: I had a similar problem for a site I frequent, which I previously used to scrape using wget and now cloudflare blocks all non-browser accesses.  I found an extension called "SingleFile" that does the job.  Conveniently it also seems to have the "after DOM content is loaded" piece built-in (and enabled via the add-on's preferences).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a traffic monitoring service like `iftop`. This tool shows connections based on the hostname (or IP if you wish).

```
 #!/bin/bash
 while ( iftop -t -s 5 2>/dev/null | grep www.domain.ltd >/dev/null ) ; do
   echo "still loading"
 done
```

Limitations:

- needs `root` to run
- assumes proper hostname resolution (will fail e.g. with youtube, where they use all sorts of hostnames but not youtube)
- not sure about IPv6 support in hostname resolution
- needs a few seconds to properly see traffic
- what about websites that constantly reload some element?

---

Alternatively `nethogs` will do a per-process analysis and shows sent and received. E.g. for 2 counts with 2-second delay:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 while ( nethogs -t -c 2 -d 2 2>/dev/null | grep firefox >/dev/null ) ; do
   echo "still loading"
 done
```

Limitations:

- needs `root` to run
- watches a process: if the web browser has other tabs constantly loading data, it would fail. (e.g. music from a website)
- needs a few seconds to properly see traffic

---

Or `tcpdump`, here limited to incoming TCP packets and stopped by `timeout`

```
while ( timeout  3 tcpdump 'tcp' -Q in -q 2>/dev/null |
        grep www.domain.ltd >/dev/null) ; do
  echo "still loading"
done
```

Limitations: see `iftop`

---

Conclusion: all methods are based on network traffic monitoring, this means they all need a few seconds to analyze said traffic and might actually help when it comes to make sure big websites are loaded, but would not speed up the whole thing in case of small websites.

Answer (score 1):

I accepted @Fiximan's answer because it solves the problem mentioned in the question. In my particular case though (I try to print a website with a lot of MathJax formulas) his solution doesn't work because after loading the page the formulas are still rendering. If you have a similar case where you need to wait until the page is loaded AND some rendering processes are finished then you can use the following solution: You have to add some JavaScript to the page source to make it work. So either the site is yours or you have to download the page, manipulate the source code and start some local server.

**General solution**

If you want to call a bash script after a page has finished loading (incl. javascript):

*HTML*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>This is the page title</title>
  <script>
      // Save the page title in a variable
      let pageTitle = document.title;
      // Set the page title to something like...
      document.title = "Page is loading..."
      // If page has finished loading
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
          // Set page title to original page title
          document.title = pageTitle;
      });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello world!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

*Bash*

```
# Open new tab
firefox -new-tab "www.domain.tld"

# Wait 1 second
sleep 1

# Wait until page has finished loading...
  while (xdotool search --name "Page is loading... - Mozilla Firefox" > /dev/null 2>&1) ; do
    sleep 0.1
  done

# Then execute new command
# < some command >
```

**MathJax 3 solution**

In my case I want to wait until the page has finished loading and MathJax has finished rendering. So I have to move the part "Set page title to original page title" to the MathJax configuration:

```
<script>
  window.MathJax = {
    // ...
    // < your configurations >
    // ...
    startup: {
      // If page has finished loading
      pageReady() {
        // If MathJax has finished typesetting
        return MathJax.startup.defaultPageReady().then(function() {
          // Set page title to original page title
          document.title = "This is the page title";
        });
      }
    }
    {{ end }}
  };
</script>
```

Comment: Perhaps this could be a Tampermonkey script. I wonder if the printing can also be accomplished via JS, in which case the Tampermonkey script could do the whole job.